# Is changing `require` to concatenate Ruby files brilliant or crazy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When booting a Rails application with lots of dependencies, a lot of time is spent (I think) in `require`ing files.

Suppose you were to create a deploy process that converted all `require` statements to file concatenations, using the same rules (don't get the same file twice, etc). Essentially, it would treat Ruby the way the asset pipeline treats javascript.

Would this make a real speed difference? Would it create any issues - for instance, with variable scope - other than making it harder to trace errors to their original source files?

In short, **is this brilliant or crazy?**

### Update

As pst points out, this would be pointless in production, where the server likely loads everything once, then forks to handle new requests.

But consider the test environment, where you boot your Rails app every time you run your tests. Pre-concatenating all your gems could have an effect similar to the Spork gem.

I suppose my real question is **how much time is spent in `require` vs parsing the contents of the files**.

Comment: I think if there was an impact, the biggest difference would be the boot time for a rails application.

Comment: I think, you have lots of free time if you think about doing stuff like this :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - it's true! I live in an underground bunker and have a near endless supply of canned goods. Each morning at alarm time, I'm dumped from my bed into a waiting pair of pants, both legs simultaneously, and sent scrambling to a control room, where a computer scores me based on number of near-pointless questions asked on StackOverflow, and doles out oxygen accordingly.

Comment: Haha, best comment I've seen on SO for quite some time :D

Comment: @NathanLong: oh yeah, you *do* ask many questions. Now I'm not sure whether that was a joke or not :)

Comment: Nathan, you will make better use of your spare time by waking up in the morning, eating your breakfast and doing a small warm-up exercise, working during the day, and going for a good 8-hour sleep in the evening after you jog for 10 minutes during the next 3 weeks, while you taper off caffeine.

Answer (score 4):

You'll be happy to see what made it into Ruby 2.0:
http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7158

Comment: Thanks for linking that. Actually, I had seen that discussion, and it's what made me think of this question in the first place: what if instead of speeding up this process, we could skip it? In other words, instead of doing lots of `require`s at boot time, we could just do one `require 'compiled_gems'`?

Answer (score 2):

tldr; it *will make **no difference** amortized across requests<sup>1</sup>* - any trivial start up cost is inconsequential<sup>2</sup>.

<sup>1</sup> A much better way to "increase performance" is just to reuse processes - e.g. only load a process once for N requests (which implies only "running" the `require` statements once) - as is *already* done.

<sup>2</sup> For those who are really interested in if "it will parse faster", please run a benchmark. Then realize that it doesn't matter - *even saving a second on start up is of no importance* to a web-server infrastructure. (Of course, it would be only milliseconds faster - from a few additional disk seeks - if at all.)

Comment: Your point about reusing processes in production is a good one. I guess what I should have asked is about doing the same thing for your gems before booting in development and testing environments.

Comment: 1) How long is the current process? 2) What percent of the execution time is "taken" with the `require`? It is the same thing. *It doesn't matter if `require` is instantaneous or takes tens of milliseconds.* (Said in cliche: "This is not the require you're looking for.")